# Sample size needed to detect a three-way interaction?

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, sample-size, statistical-power

I am hoping to propose a study for which the predicted outcome would be a three-way interaction. I am wondering if this is going to be possible at all with the resources at my disposal, or if the sample size I would need in order to do this would be prohibitive.

The predicted three-way interaction would be the result of one (manipulated) 2-level categorical variable and 2 (measured) continuous variables.

Can anyone give me a sense as to how many participants I would need to recruit in order to have decent power to detect such an effect? Even a vague sense would be enormously helpful-- I don't need to run the study right away, so there would be time for more precision later, but right now I could really use some insight into whether it even makes sense to propose such a study (and if so, how many participants I need to estimate that we'll need).

Thank you in advance for any advice!

P.S. I'm an early career grad student with limited stats knowledge. Thank you for bearing with me...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but the outcome is a three-way interaction? Or do you mean there is a three-way interaction on the right-hand side (i.e., as an explanatory term)? Also, what type of statistical model/tests do you plan to perform?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but I am predicting that there will be a significant three-way interaction-- specifically, that the manipulation will have an effect only (or most strongly) when the two continuous predictor variables are each at a certain level. I plan on testing this with a regression, entering each of the three main effects, the three two-way interactions and the three way interaction as predictors. Does that answer your questions?

Comment: "*specifically, that the manipulation will have an effect only when the two continuous predictor variables are each at a certain level*" would not usually be a three way interaction. Why not test this more directly?

Comment: How do you mean? If the value of the DV depends on (1) the manipulation, (2) the first continuous IV, and (3) the second continuous IV, and the way the manipulation affects the DV depends on what level the 2nd and 3rd IVs are at, isn't that a 3-way interaction? If there is a more direct way though I am certainly eager to hear about it!